# MVC application : Url Helper throw HttpException "Type casting is failed!"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working in a team project (MVC aplication). After the i made a update, the application starts to give the HttpException "Type casting is failed!" and i don't know why.

The code:

```
public static class UrlHelper
{
    private static System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper _urlHelper;

    public static System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper GetFromContext()
    {
        if (_urlHelper == null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException("Current httpcontext is null!");
            }

            if (!(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler is System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler))
            {
                throw new HttpException("Type casting is failed!");
            }

            _urlHelper = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(((System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler).RequestContext);
        }

        return _urlHelper;
    }
}
```

The error ocorre in the following line of code and "The type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler' exists in both 'System.Web.Mvc.dll' and 'System.Web.Mvc.dll'"

```
if (!(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler is System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler))
```

Any Idea?

**[EDIT WITH MORE INFORMATION]**

- I try the following things without any success.
- I clean the solution.
- I delete the bin of my project and the bin of all dependencies of
  them.
- I check for changes that i have mad (in the main project and
  dependencies) in other trying to see if they have impact of error.

**Util information:**

- Using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with Update 3, version
  12.0.30723.00
- Using Microsoft .NET FrameWork, version 4.5.51650
- Using System.Web, version 4.0.30319
- Using MVC 5, version 5.1.0.0

Comment: What updates have you made? Was it an update to the code above or something unrelated that is being caught in this helper?

Comment: The upadte that i made, doesn't affect this code, but affects other code of my application. The real problem is in the fact that in the team friends project's this just not happen, it's only in my project and i don't know why.

Comment: Ok, so you need to show us the changes that you've made. Have you added references? Created new project? Etc. Did the code work before your changes?

Comment: I checked the changes, a it is a lot of them, but no one of them changes references. Also we didn't create a new project. This is a big project, so it's almost impossible show all changes.

My Code work find before this update. But as I said, all of my team made update, and this are only happening to me.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your solution and doing a rebuild?

Comment: Yes i mad, check my changes and look all the things that i already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in web.config file. In their, some of the configurations wasn't right. After put all the configurations correctly, the problem was solve. I don't know exactly what cause this specific error, i just know the problem was the web.config file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if (!(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler is System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler))
 {
       throw new HttpException("Type casting is failed!");
 }
```